# When the Response Data of the Jmeter is in XML format, in the output CSV file what we generate is in non readable form.How to overcome it

Tags: csv, jmeter, performance-testing

When the Response Data of the Jmeter is in XML format, in the output CSV file what we generate after the test run completion is in non readable form.How to overcome it.Else is there any way that after running via Non-Gui mode without writing response data in the output CSV file but we should see the response data in the view results in tree Listener.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the response file in .jtl format instead of .csv. Then, use any XML editor or Excel to view that. Excel will show you some pop-up, you just need to click ok and proceed.

JTL in excel:-
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: It didn't help me as it looks very scrambled when I used XML editor.I want technique if any like even if in the output file if we are not logging the response is there any way that I can see the response data in view results in tree listener

Comment: Check it with excel also. You can click on a particular request and see the request and response data of it in view result listener. I have updated the answer for the view of jtl with excel. Check if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can't see the response data if you are not logging response!!!

Follow these step by step (Non-GUI):

1. Uncomment these following lines in your `jmeter.properties` file. This file locates in your bin directory. After adding these lines, you have to restart the JMeter.

   > jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   >
   > jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
2. Run your script through command line like:

   > jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l test_result.jtl
3. Now open your GUI and add the View Results Tree listener and upload/browse the `test_result.jtl` file.

Now, you will be able to see the responses through GUI.